# Give time gap between two consecutive javafx animations

Tags: animation, javafx

I have a series of animation which is started one after the other as shown in below code.

```
animPath.playFromStart();
        animPath.setOnFinished((evt) -> {
            TranslateTransition tCut = showText(lblCutover);
            tCut.playFromStart();
            lblCutover.setVisible(true);
            tCut.setOnFinished((e11) -> {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ARUOLandingPageController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                TranslateTransition tCutBack = hideText(lblCutover);
                tCutBack.playFromStart();
                tCutBack.setOnFinished((e12) -> {
                    lblCutover.setVisible(false);

                    anim11.playFromStart();
                    anim11.setOnFinished((evt11) -> {
                         (Some new animation)...
                    });
                });
            });
        });
```

I have two types of animations. One is path animation and the other one is translate animation. No time gap is required after the path animation.
But after one translate animation is finished I want to give a time gap of 10 seconds for the next animation to start.
I used `Thread.Sleep(10000)` but it stops my entire stage. The stage becomes not responding if I click anywhere. 
Is there a way I can just put time gap between these animations without affecting any other section in my ui?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put multiple transitions into [SequentialTransition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/SequentialTransition.html), where one of them can be a [PauseTransition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/PauseTransition.html) with a `Duration.seconds(10)`.

Comment: This will give the gap between all the animations. I have two type of animation path transition and translate transition I don't want any gap after the path transition animation but a time gap of 10 seconds after translate transition animation.

Comment: @HARSHITASETHI, have you looked to the example in the javadoc of  SequentialTransition (linked above)? You will just add transitions something like: animSeq.getChildren().add(animPath, animTranslate, animPause);

Comment: @HARSHITASETHI, were you able to add pause to your transitions? If not update your question with current latest code and the error if any.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Pause Transition is the thing I was actually looking for.